# How to query mongoose such that the search have to match two ids

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this code which searches for documents based on two ids.

```
User.find({
    $or: [
        { id: req.body.myId },
        { id: req.body.id }
    ]
}, function(err, users) {
    console.log(users)
});
```

This works fine, however, let's assume `req.body.myId` is undefined, then it would grab all documents that match `req.body.id` only. I need it to be such that if it can't be find any documents relating to one id, then it shouldn't grab anything for the other Id, giving back an empty array of users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a check before executing the query and don't execute it if one of the parameters are undefined, so you don't make unnecessary calls to MongoDB. Something like:

```
if (!req.body.myId || !req.body.id) {
    // return here empty array or whatever
}
```

By the way in your case usually the `$in` operator is used:

```
User.find({
    id: { 
       $in: [req.body.myId, req.body.id]
    }
}, function(err, users) {
    console.log(users)
});
```

Comment: +I for using the `$in` operator, I was too lazy to change the original `$or` in my answer below ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is a strange requirement but ok:

```
function findByTwoIds(id1, id2, callback) {
    if (!id1 || !id2) {
        callback(null, []);
    } else {
        User.find({
            $or: [
                { id: id1 },
                { id: id2 }
            ]
        }, callback);
    }
}
```

and use it with:

```
findByTwoIds(req.body.myId, req.body.id, function (err, users) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error:', err);
    } else {
        console.log(users);
    }
});
```